# Is the strong topology of a locally convex space always barrelled?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, locally-convex-spaces

For a locally convex space $E$ let $E_\beta$ be the space $E$ endowed with the locally convex topology $\beta(E,E')$ whose neighborhood base at zero consists of barrels, i.e., closed absolutely convex absorbing sets.

Observe that a space $E$ is barrelled if and only if $E=E_\beta$.

> **Question 1.** Is $(E_\beta)_\beta=E_\beta$ for any locally convex space? Equivalently, is the space $E_\beta$ always barrelled?

If not, then we can ask a more restricted version of Question 1.

> **Question 2.** Let $E$ be a locally convex space such that the space $E_\beta$ is normable (and separable). Is $E_\beta$ barrelled?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov The passage from $E$ to $E_\beta$ can change the dual. Just consider the space $E=C_p(K)$ of real-valued continuous functions on  an infinite compact Hausdorff space $K$, endowed with the topology of pointwise convergence. The dual $E'$ is the space of finitely supported signed measures on $K$. On the other hand, $E_\beta$ coincides with the Banach space $C(K)$ and has much larger dual (consisting of all regular sign-measures). At least $C(K)'$ contain the space $\ell_1(K)$ of countably supported sign-measures.

Comment: Taras, yes, excuse me, you are right.

Comment: For my purposes it would be very desirable to have affirmative answer at least to Question 2. I cannot imagine how a counterexample can be constructed (if it exists at all).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is negative. There are Frechet spaces $X$ whose strong duals $(X',\beta(X',X))$ are not barrelled (equivalently, not bornological by a theorem of Grothendieck). The first examples of such *non-distinguished* Frechet spaces were constructed by Köthe and Grothendieck but there are also examples which are very easy to describe: According to Taskinen the Frechet space $C(\mathbb R) \cap L^1(\mathbb R)$ of continuous Lebesgue-intergrable functions (endowed with the seminorms $\int|f(x)|dx + \sup\{|f(x)|: x\in [-n,n]\}$) is not distinguished. This answers question 1 with $E=(X',\sigma(X',X))$.

EDIT: If $M$ is a barrel in $E$ then its polar $M^\circ$ is a $\sigma(X,X')$-bounded subset of $X$ and hence it is bounded in the Frechet topology so that $M=M^{\circ\circ}$ is a $\beta(X',X)$-neighbourhood of $0$. Conversely, the typical $0$-neighbourhood $B^\circ$ in $\beta(X',X)$ with a bounded subset $B$ of $X$ is a barrel in $(X',\sigma(X',X))$.

Comment: Is it always true that for the dual space $E=(X',\sigma(X',X))$ of a Frechet space $X$ the topology generated by barrels in $E$ coincides with the topology $\beta(X',X)$?

Comment: I have editet the post. Hopefully, this answers your question.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth: You mentioned Koethe. Is there another example with sequence spaces?

Comment: Of course, the first examples were sequence spaces. You can see a characterization of distinguished Köthe space $\lambda^1(A)$ in terms of the matrix in proposition 27.17 and the classical example in 27.19 in the book *Introduction to Functional Analysis* of Meise and Vogt.

Answer (score 3):

Many examples of spaces $C_p(X)$ whose strong dual is not barrelled can be found in a recent paper "Examples of Nondistinguished Function Spaces $C_p(X)$", Journal of Convex Analysis, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $E$ be the space $C[0,1]$ of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with the norm $\|x\|=\int_0^1 |x(t)|dt$. Then $E=E_\beta$ is normable and separable, but it is not barrelled. The set $B=\{x\in E: \sup_{t\in [0,1]} |x(t)|\le1\}$ is a barrell in $E$, but it is not neighborhood at zero.

Comment: It seems to me that the space $E_\beta$ is the Banach $C[0,1]$ endowed with the sup-norm, so $E_\beta$ is barrelled and $E\ne E_\beta$. So your example does not work.